# SpringMVC conflict by @PathVariable and resources

Tags: spring-mvc, resources, conflict, path-variables

I have a problem while use Spring MVC:

I wrote a Controller, a method named 


**@RequestMapping("/{moduleName}/{subModuleName}")**

**public ModelAndView getModuleContent(@PathVariable String moduleName, @PathVariable String subModuleName) {
    
     ...
}**,

now the problem is, when I access a static resource, for example:

```
http://www.mytomcat:8080/images/testpng
```

it would mapping that controller, but I don't want this, how can I resolve the conflict?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

configure following accordingly.

```
<mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/public-resources/"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to specify regex pattern for path vars:

`@RequestMapping(value = "/{year:\\d+}/{month:\\d+}/**", method = RequestMethod.GET)`

This helps spring to avoid conflicts with `<mvc:resources/>` mapped to path like `/images/**`. If your path variable can contain all except 'images' you can try regex like this: `(?!images)`.

Answer (score 0):

You may [configure resource handlers](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-config-static-resources) for resource folders such as `/images`.

It should help, because mapping of these handlers would be more specific than `/{moduleName}/{subModuleName}`, therefore resource handlers should take precedence.